# Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

Has anyone used `tablefunc` to pivot on multiple variables as opposed to only using *row name*?

I need to do this for **billions** of rows and I'm testing out storing this data in long and wide formats and seeing if I can use `tablefunc` to go from long to wide format more efficiently than with regular aggregate functions.  I'll have about 100 measurements made every minute for around 300 entities. Often, we will need to compare the different measurements made for a given second for a given entity, so we will need to go to wide format very often. Also, the measurements made on a particular entity are highly variable.

As sample data, I've edited the data used in a response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499):

```
 CREATE TEMP TABLE t4 (
  timeof   timestamp
 ,entity    character
 ,status    integer
 ,ct        integer);

 INSERT INTO t4 VALUES 
  ('2012-01-01', 'a', 1, 1)
 ,('2012-01-01', 'a', 0, 2)
 ,('2012-01-02', 'b', 1, 3)
 ,('2012-01-02', 'c', 0, 4);

 SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     'SELECT timeof, entity, status, ct
      FROM   t4
      ORDER  BY 1,2,3'
     ,$$VALUES (1::text), (0::text)$$)
 AS ct ("Section" timestamp, "Attribute" character, "1" int, "0" int);
```

Returns:

| Section | Attribute | 1 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | a | 1 | 2 |
| 2012-01-02 00:00:00 | **b** | 3 | 4 |

So as the documentation states, the *extra* column aka 'Attribute' is assumed to be the same for each *row name* aka 'Section'. Thus, it reports **b** for the second row even though 'entity' also has a **'c'** value for that 'timeof' value.

Desired Output:

| Section | Attribute | 1 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | a | 1 | 2 |
| 2012-01-02 00:00:00 | b | 3 |  |
| 2012-01-02 00:00:00 | c |  | 4 |

Some resources that I used: [1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html), [2](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/categories/24-tablefunc)

How do I do it?

Comment: +1 Nice question with a (highly appreciated) working test case, clearly demonstrating the problem. Only the PostgreSQL version is missing. I assumed current version 9.2. But the solution is the same for the last couple of major versions.

Comment: The solution is valid only for this problem, and I mean only 'this problem' because it isn't valid for pivot tables over two column indexes. So, the title is not true or the answer should be the second one (id=answer-15559942)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem with your query is that **`b`** and **`c`** share the same timestamp `2012-01-02 00:00:00`, and you have the `timestamp` column `timeof` first in your query, so - even though you added bold emphasis - `b` and `c` are just extra columns that fall in the same group `2012-01-02 00:00:00`. Only the first (`b`) is returned since [(quoting the manual)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.49.5.7):

> The `row_name` column must be first. The `category` and `value` columns must be the last two columns, in that order. Any columns between `row_name` and `category` are treated as "extra". The "extra" columns are **expected to be the same** for all rows with the same `row_name` value.

Bold emphasis mine.
Just revert the order of the first two columns to make `entity` the row name and it works as desired:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT entity, timeof, status, ct
    FROM   t4
    ORDER  BY 1'
 , 'VALUES (1), (0)'
   ) AS ct (
      "Attribute" character
    , "Section" timestamp
    , "status_1" int
    , "status_0" int
      );
```

`entity` must be unique, of course.

#### Reiterate

- **`row_name`** *first*
- (optional) **`extra`** columns *next*
- **`category`** (as defined by the second parameter) and **`value`** *last*.

Extra columns are filled from the *first* row from each `row_name` partition. Values from other rows are ignored, there is only one column per `row_name` to fill. Typically those would be the same for every row of one `row_name`, but that's up to you.

Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

#### For the different setup [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15574405/939860):

```sql
SELECT localt, entity
     , msrmnt01, msrmnt02, msrmnt03, msrmnt04, msrmnt05  -- , more?
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY localt, entity)::int AS row_name
        , localt, entity -- additional columns
        , msrmnt, val
   FROM   test
-- WHERE  ???   -- instead of LIMIT at the end
   ORDER  BY localt, entity, msrmnt
-- LIMIT ???'   -- instead of LIMIT at the end
, 'SELECT generate_series(1,5)'  -- more?
   ) AS ct (row_name int, localt timestamp, entity int
          , msrmnt01 float8, msrmnt02 float8, msrmnt03 float8, msrmnt04 float8, msrmnt05 float8 -- , more?
            )
LIMIT 1000  -- ?!
```

No wonder the queries in your test perform terribly. Your test setup has 14M rows and you process *all* of them before throwing most away with `LIMIT 1000`. For a reduced result set add `WHERE` conditions or a `LIMIT` to the source query!

Plus, the array you work with is needlessly expensive on top of it. I generated a surrogate row name with `dense_rank()` instead.

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cW5D_0Kj) - with simpler test setup and fewer rows.

Comment: Hey Erwin, thank you very much for the response. I'll go ahead and grant you credit but I think I left in some ambiguity in my inquiry. I'll post back when I have time.

Comment: @AndreSilva: I am sure there is a way. Please ask your question as *question*. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this for context and drop a comment here linking back to get my attention.

Answer (score 13):

In my original question I should have used this for my sample data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t4 (
 timeof    date
,entity    integer
,status    integer
,ct        integer);
INSERT INTO t4 VALUES 
 ('2012-01-01', 1, 1, 1)
,('2012-01-01', 1, 0, 2)
,('2012-01-01', 3, 0, 3)
,('2012-01-02', 2, 1, 4)
,('2012-01-02', 3, 1, 5)
,('2012-01-02', 3, 0, 6);
```

With this I have to pivot on both timeof and entity. Since `tablefunc` only uses one column for the pivoting, you need to find a way to stuff both dimensions in that column. (http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/categories/24-tablefunc). I went with the array, just like the example on in that link.

```
SELECT (timestamp 'epoch' + row_name[1] * INTERVAL '1 second')::date 
           as localt, 
           row_name[2] As entity, status1, status0
FROM crosstab('SELECT ARRAY[extract(epoch from timeof), entity] as row_name,
                    status, ct
               FROM t4 
               ORDER BY timeof, entity, status'
     ,$$VALUES (1::text), (0::text)$$) 
          as ct (row_name integer[], status1 int, status0 int)
```

FWIW, I tried using a character array and so far it looks like this is faster for my setup; 9.2.3 Postgresql.

This is the result and desired output.

```
localt           | entity | status1 | status0
--------------------------+---------+--------
2012-01-01       |   1    |    1    |   2
2012-01-01       |   3    |         |   3
2012-01-02       |   2    |    4    |  
2012-01-02       |   3    |    5    |   6
```

I'm curious how this performs on a much larger data-set and will report back at a later date.

Comment: Very interesting. I think this should be marked as the valid answer. The first one now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc#15421607 not answer to the question because entities with values at same time will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I ran this on a table closer to my use case. Either I'm doing it wrong or crosstab is not suitable for my use.

First I made some similar data:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    id serial primary key,
    msrmnt integer,
    entity integer,
    localt timestamp,
    val    double precision
);
CREATE INDEX ix_test_msrmnt
   ON public.test (msrmnt);
 CREATE INDEX ix_public_test_201201_entity
   ON public.test (entity);
CREATE INDEX ix_public_test_201201_localt
  ON public.test (localt);
insert into public.test (msrmnt, entity, localt, val)
select *
from(
SELECT msrmnt, entity, localt, random() as val 
FROM generate_series('2012-01-01'::timestamp, '2012-01-01 23:59:00'::timestamp, interval '1 minutes') as localt
join 
(select *
FROM generate_series(1, 50, 1) as msrmnt) as msrmnt
on 1=1
join 
(select *
FROM generate_series(1, 200, 1) as entity) as entity
on 1=1) as data;
```

Then I ran the crosstab code a couple times:

```
explain analyze
SELECT (timestamp 'epoch' + row_name[1] * INTERVAL '1 second')::date As localt, row_name[2] as entity
    ,msrmnt01,msrmnt02,msrmnt03,msrmnt04,msrmnt05,msrmnt06,msrmnt07,msrmnt08,msrmnt09,msrmnt10
    ,msrmnt11,msrmnt12,msrmnt13,msrmnt14,msrmnt15,msrmnt16,msrmnt17,msrmnt18,msrmnt19,msrmnt20
    ,msrmnt21,msrmnt22,msrmnt23,msrmnt24,msrmnt25,msrmnt26,msrmnt27,msrmnt28,msrmnt29,msrmnt30
    ,msrmnt31,msrmnt32,msrmnt33,msrmnt34,msrmnt35,msrmnt36,msrmnt37,msrmnt38,msrmnt39,msrmnt40
    ,msrmnt41,msrmnt42,msrmnt43,msrmnt44,msrmnt45,msrmnt46,msrmnt47,msrmnt48,msrmnt49,msrmnt50
    FROM crosstab('SELECT ARRAY[extract(epoch from localt), entity] as row_name, msrmnt, val
               FROM public.test
               ORDER BY localt, entity, msrmnt',$$VALUES  ( 1::text),( 2::text),( 3::text),( 4::text),( 5::text),( 6::text),( 7::text),( 8::text),( 9::text),(10::text)
                                                         ,(11::text),(12::text),(13::text),(14::text),(15::text),(16::text),(17::text),(18::text),(19::text),(20::text)
                                                         ,(21::text),(22::text),(23::text),(24::text),(25::text),(26::text),(27::text),(28::text),(29::text),(30::text)
                                                         ,(31::text),(32::text),(33::text),(34::text),(35::text),(36::text),(37::text),(38::text),(39::text),(40::text)
                                                         ,(41::text),(42::text),(43::text),(44::text),(45::text),(46::text),(47::text),(48::text),(49::text),(50::text)$$)
        as ct (row_name integer[],msrmnt01 double precision, msrmnt02 double precision,msrmnt03 double precision, msrmnt04 double precision,msrmnt05 double precision, 
                    msrmnt06 double precision,msrmnt07 double precision, msrmnt08 double precision,msrmnt09 double precision, msrmnt10 double precision
                 ,msrmnt11 double precision, msrmnt12 double precision,msrmnt13 double precision, msrmnt14 double precision,msrmnt15 double precision, 
                    msrmnt16 double precision,msrmnt17 double precision, msrmnt18 double precision,msrmnt19 double precision, msrmnt20 double precision
                 ,msrmnt21 double precision, msrmnt22 double precision,msrmnt23 double precision, msrmnt24 double precision,msrmnt25 double precision, 
                    msrmnt26 double precision,msrmnt27 double precision, msrmnt28 double precision,msrmnt29 double precision, msrmnt30 double precision
                 ,msrmnt31 double precision, msrmnt32 double precision,msrmnt33 double precision, msrmnt34 double precision,msrmnt35 double precision, 
                    msrmnt36 double precision,msrmnt37 double precision, msrmnt38 double precision,msrmnt39 double precision, msrmnt40 double precision
                 ,msrmnt41 double precision, msrmnt42 double precision,msrmnt43 double precision, msrmnt44 double precision,msrmnt45 double precision, 
                    msrmnt46 double precision,msrmnt47 double precision, msrmnt48 double precision,msrmnt49 double precision, msrmnt50 double precision)
limit 1000
```

Obtaining this on the third try:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=432) (actual time=110236.673..110237.667 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Function Scan on crosstab ct  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=432) (actual time=110236.672..110237.598 rows=1000 loops=1)
Total runtime: 110699.598 ms
```

Then I ran the standard solution a couple times:

```
explain analyze
select localt, entity, 
 max(case when msrmnt =  1 then val else null end) as msrmnt01
,max(case when msrmnt =  2 then val else null end) as msrmnt02
,max(case when msrmnt =  3 then val else null end) as msrmnt03
,max(case when msrmnt =  4 then val else null end) as msrmnt04
,max(case when msrmnt =  5 then val else null end) as msrmnt05
,max(case when msrmnt =  6 then val else null end) as msrmnt06
,max(case when msrmnt =  7 then val else null end) as msrmnt07
,max(case when msrmnt =  8 then val else null end) as msrmnt08
,max(case when msrmnt =  9 then val else null end) as msrmnt09
,max(case when msrmnt = 10 then val else null end) as msrmnt10
,max(case when msrmnt = 11 then val else null end) as msrmnt11
,max(case when msrmnt = 12 then val else null end) as msrmnt12
,max(case when msrmnt = 13 then val else null end) as msrmnt13
,max(case when msrmnt = 14 then val else null end) as msrmnt14
,max(case when msrmnt = 15 then val else null end) as msrmnt15
,max(case when msrmnt = 16 then val else null end) as msrmnt16
,max(case when msrmnt = 17 then val else null end) as msrmnt17
,max(case when msrmnt = 18 then val else null end) as msrmnt18
,max(case when msrmnt = 19 then val else null end) as msrmnt19
,max(case when msrmnt = 20 then val else null end) as msrmnt20
,max(case when msrmnt = 21 then val else null end) as msrmnt21
,max(case when msrmnt = 22 then val else null end) as msrmnt22
,max(case when msrmnt = 23 then val else null end) as msrmnt23
,max(case when msrmnt = 24 then val else null end) as msrmnt24
,max(case when msrmnt = 25 then val else null end) as msrmnt25
,max(case when msrmnt = 26 then val else null end) as msrmnt26
,max(case when msrmnt = 27 then val else null end) as msrmnt27
,max(case when msrmnt = 28 then val else null end) as msrmnt28
,max(case when msrmnt = 29 then val else null end) as msrmnt29
,max(case when msrmnt = 30 then val else null end) as msrmnt30
,max(case when msrmnt = 31 then val else null end) as msrmnt31
,max(case when msrmnt = 32 then val else null end) as msrmnt32
,max(case when msrmnt = 33 then val else null end) as msrmnt33
,max(case when msrmnt = 34 then val else null end) as msrmnt34
,max(case when msrmnt = 35 then val else null end) as msrmnt35
,max(case when msrmnt = 36 then val else null end) as msrmnt36
,max(case when msrmnt = 37 then val else null end) as msrmnt37
,max(case when msrmnt = 38 then val else null end) as msrmnt38
,max(case when msrmnt = 39 then val else null end) as msrmnt39
,max(case when msrmnt = 40 then val else null end) as msrmnt40
,max(case when msrmnt = 41 then val else null end) as msrmnt41
,max(case when msrmnt = 42 then val else null end) as msrmnt42
,max(case when msrmnt = 43 then val else null end) as msrmnt43
,max(case when msrmnt = 44 then val else null end) as msrmnt44
,max(case when msrmnt = 45 then val else null end) as msrmnt45
,max(case when msrmnt = 46 then val else null end) as msrmnt46
,max(case when msrmnt = 47 then val else null end) as msrmnt47
,max(case when msrmnt = 48 then val else null end) as msrmnt48
,max(case when msrmnt = 49 then val else null end) as msrmnt49
,max(case when msrmnt = 50 then val else null end) as msrmnt50
from sample
group by localt, entity
limit 1000
```

Obtaining this on the third try:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=2257339.69..2270224.77 rows=1000 width=24) (actual time=19795.984..20090.626 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=2257339.69..5968242.35 rows=288000 width=24) (actual time=19795.983..20090.496 rows=1000 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=2257339.69..2293339.91 rows=14400088 width=24) (actual time=19795.626..19808.820 rows=50001 loops=1)
              Sort Key: localt
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 478568kB
              ->  Seq Scan on sample  (cost=0.00..249883.88 rows=14400088 width=24) (actual time=0.013..2245.247 rows=14400000 loops=1)
Total runtime: 20197.565 ms
```

So, for my case, it appears so far that crosstab is not a solution. And this is just one day when I'll have multiple years. In fact, I will probably have to go with wide format (not normalized) tables, despite the fact that which measurements are made for entities is variable and new ones are introduced, but I won't go into that here.

Here's some of my settings using Postgres 9.2.3:

```
name                    setting
max_connections             100
shared_buffers          2097152
effective_cache_size    6291456
maintenance_work_mem    1048576
work_mem                 262144
```

Comment: Just stumbled across this. Never took notice back then. I added a solution to my answer. Much too late now, but I have been linking to this question and I didn't want to let this go unanswered.