# Sum by month and put months as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, case, crosstab

#### Background

I have time series data on a monthly basis and I would like to sum values for each ID, grouped by month and then have the month names as columns rather than as rows.

#### Example

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+
| id | extra_info | month | value |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
| 1  | abc        | jan   | 10    |
| 1  | abc        | feb   | 20    |
| 2  | def        | jan   | 10    |
| 2  | def        | feb   | 5     |
| 1  | abc        | jan   | 15    |
| 3  | ghi        | mar   | 15    |
```

#### Desired Result

```
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| id | extra_info | jan | feb | mar |
+----+------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 1  | abc        | 25  | 20  | 0   |
| 2  | def        | 10  | 5   | 0   |
| 3  | ghi        | 0   | 0   | 15  |
```

#### Current Approach

I can easily group by month, summing the values. Which gets me to:

```
-----------------------------------
| id | extra_info | month | value |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
| 1  | abc        | jan   | 25    |
| 1  | abc        | feb   | 20    |
| 2  | def        | jan   | 10    |
| 2  | def        | feb   | 5     |
| 3  | ghi        | mar   | 15    |
```

But I now need those months as column names. Not sure where to go from here.

#### Additional Information

- In terms of language, this query is to be run in postgres.
- The months above are just examples, obviously the real data set is much larger and covers all 12 months across thousands of IDs

Any ideas from an SQL guru very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Setup

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id int
, extra_info varchar(3)
, month date
, value int
);
   
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, 'abc', '2012-01-01', 10)
, (1, 'abc', '2012-02-01', 20)
, (2, 'def', '2012-01-01', 10)
, (2, 'def', '2012-02-01',  5)
, (1, 'abc', '2012-01-01', 15)
, (3, 'ghi', '2012-03-01', 15)
;
```

### `crosstab()`

I would use `crosstab()` from the additional [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) module. Install once per database with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

How to deal with "extra" columns:

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

Advanced usage:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

#### Query

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT id, min(extra_info), month, sum(value) AS value
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY id, month
   ORDER  BY id, month
   $$
 , $$
   VALUES
     ('jan'::text), ('feb'), ('mar'), ('apr'), ('may'), ('jun')
   , ('jul'),       ('aug'), ('sep'), ('oct'), ('nov'), ('dec')
   $$
   ) AS ct (id  int, extra text
          , jan int, feb int, mar int, apr int, may int, jun int
          , jul int, aug int, sep int, oct int, nov int, dec int);
```

Obviously, you can only output *one* `extra_info` per `id`. I pick
`min(extra_info)` since you didn't specify. If all are the same per `id`, you could also group by it additionally.

Result:

```
 id | extra | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | jul | aug | sep | oct | nov | dec
----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
  1 | abc   |  25 |  20 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
  2 | def   |  10 |   5 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
  3 | ghi   |     |     |  15 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=586bfc402c13d6c8619e8ea80c11aab3)*

Installing the `tablefunc` module (once per database) incurs some overhead, but queries are typically faster and shorter.

### Pure SQL

If you can't or won't install the additional module, plain SQL got s bit faster with the aggregate `FILTER` clause added with Postgres 9.4. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

```sql
SELECT id, min(extra_info) AS extra
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'jan') AS jan
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'feb') AS feb
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'mar') AS mar
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'apr') AS apr
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'may') AS may
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'jun') AS jun
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'jul') AS jul
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'aug') AS aug
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'sep') AS sep
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'oct') AS oct
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'nov') AS nov
     , sum(value) FILTER (WHERE month = 'dec') AS dec
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id
ORDER  BY id;
```

#### `0` instead of `NULL`

To output 0 instead of NULL for missing values, use `COALESCE` for either query:

```sql
SELECT id, extra
     , COALESCE(jan, 0) AS jan
     , COALESCE(feb, 0) AS feb
     , COALESCE(mar, 0) AS mar
     , COALESCE(apr, 0) AS apr
     , COALESCE(may, 0) AS may
     , COALESCE(jun, 0) AS jun
     , COALESCE(jul, 0) AS jul
     , COALESCE(aug, 0) AS aug
     , COALESCE(sep, 0) AS sep
     , COALESCE(oct, 0) AS oct
     , COALESCE(nov, 0) AS nov
     , COALESCE(dec, 0) AS dec
FROM  (<query from above>)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=586bfc402c13d6c8619e8ea80c11aab3)*

Comment: I knew you would come in with a `crosstab` answer. :)

Comment: @bluefeet: We had this situation before, if I remember correctly. :)

Comment: Ironically, we did look at Crosstab and it seemed pretty complex so I asked here hoping for a generic way. At now I know the consensus appears to be universal :P

Answer (score 9):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to turn the rows into columns:

```
select id,
  extra_info,
  sum(case when month = 'jan' then value else 0 end) jan,
  sum(case when month = 'feb' then value else 0 end) feb,
  sum(case when month = 'mar' then value else 0 end) mar,
  sum(case when month = 'apr' then value else 0 end) apr,
  sum(case when month = 'may' then value else 0 end) may,
  sum(case when month = 'jun' then value else 0 end) jun,
  sum(case when month = 'jul' then value else 0 end) jul,
  sum(case when month = 'aug' then value else 0 end) aug,
  sum(case when month = 'sep' then value else 0 end) sep,
  sum(case when month = 'oct' then value else 0 end) oct,
  sum(case when month = 'nov' then value else 0 end) nov,
  sum(case when month = 'dec' then value else 0 end) "dec"
from yt
group by id, extra_info
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4736b/6)

Comment: Thanks! I vaguely remember seeing something like this before, wish my brain was more reliable! Is there some way of doing it without manually handling the cases? Works great for months but I'm wondering if there's a more generic form which could be applied to categories with 100s of entries?

Comment: @PeterHamilton Yes, you can use the `crosstab` function. Here is a great answer from another user -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Had a version that was using sub querys for each month and would take hours to build verse seconds using this.