# Select value as column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, entity-attribute-value, crosstab

If I have a table containing:

```
game       powerup   used
memory     1         12
memory     2         10
bejeweled  2         88
bejeweled  3         54
```

...where the (number of) different possible values of `powerup` are unknown, is there a way to `SELECT` this as something like

```
game       1_used  2_used  3_used
memory     12      10
bejeweled          88      54
```

I'm interested in pure SQL or PostgreSQL answers.

Note: This is an academical question, I don't have a use case at the moment. Answer it for your enjoyment or for the good of the site, not my personal benefit :)

Comment: The transpose operation is known as `PIVOT`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum by month and put months as columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598112/sum-by-month-and-put-months-as-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT game
,MAX(CASE WHEN powerup = 1 THEN used ELSE NULL END) AS used1
,MAX(CASE WHEN powerup = 2 THEN used ELSE NULL END) AS used2
,MAX(CASE WHEN powerup = 3 THEN used ELSE NULL END) AS used3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY game;
```

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║   GAME    ║ USED1  ║ USED2 ║ USED3  ║
╠═══════════╬════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ bejeweled ║ (null) ║    88 ║ 54     ║
║ memory    ║ 12     ║    10 ║ (null) ║
╚═══════════╩════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/ec053/7)

Comment: I'm afraid this harcodes the values 1, 2 and 3, which aren't known when writing the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;
CREATE TABLE meuk
        ( game varchar
        , powerup INTEGER NOT NULL
        , used INTEGER NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (game,powerup)
        );

INSERT INTO meuk(game, powerup, used) VALUES
( 'memory' , 1,12)
,( 'memory' , 2,10)
,( 'bejeweled' , 2,88)
,( 'bejeweled' , 3,54)
        ;

 -- using a self-join as
 -- a poor man's pivot.
WITH dom AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT game AS game
        FROM meuk
        )
SELECT m0.game AS game
        , m1.used AS used_1
        , m2.used AS used_2
        , m3.used AS used_3
FROM dom m0
LEFT JOIN meuk m1 ON m1.game = m0.game AND m1.powerup = 1
LEFT JOIN meuk m2 ON m2.game = m0.game AND m2.powerup = 2
LEFT JOIN meuk m3 ON m3.game = m0.game AND m3.powerup = 3
        ;
```

RESULTS:

```
   game    | used_1 | used_2 | used_3 
-----------+--------+--------+--------
 bejeweled |        |     88 |     54
 memory    |     12 |     10 |       
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this harcodes the values 1, 2 and 3, which aren't known when writing the query.

Comment: Cannot be done without dynamic SQL. Please take a look at the crosstab() function (which, in its present form, also needs the de desired value list and column names. IIRC).

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE test_1
        ( game varchar(10)
        , powerup INTEGER NOT NULL
        , used INTEGER NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO test_1(game, powerup, used) 
SELECT 'memory' , 1,12 UNION ALL
SELECT 'memory' , 2,10 UNION ALL
SELECT  'bejeweled' , 2,88 UNION ALL
SELECT  'bejeweled' , 3,54 

select * from test_1

DECLARE @COLUMNS varchar(max) 
SELECT @COLUMNS = COALESCE(@COLUMNS+'],[' ,'') +  CAST(powerup as varchar)
FROM test_1
GROUP BY powerup

SET @COLUMNS = '[' + @COLUMNS + ']'

EXECUTE ('select * from test_1
pivot (SUM(used) for powerup IN ('+ @COLUMNS +')) as used_t')
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I am guessing that this answer is sql server syntax and the question is tagged with postgresql.

Comment: just share the approach, how he could do the same in postgresql