# Postgres PIVOT table on aggregated count

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, postgres-crosstab

I am trying to create a pivot table in Postgres from the following table
named `product_info`:

```
CREATE TABLE product_info (
    ID varchar(10),
    date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    product VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    product_cost integer 
);

INSERT INTO product_info(ID, date, product, product_cost)
VALUES
  ('1', 'AUG-23','Laptop',100),
  ('1', 'AUG-23','Phone',80),
  ('1', 'AUG-23','Keypad',50),
  ('1', 'SEP-23','Laptop',200),
  ('1', 'SEP-23','Phone',100),
  ('1', 'SEP-23','Ipad',150),
  ('1', 'SEP-23','Keypad',80),
  ('2', 'AUG-23','Laptop',100),
  ('2', 'AUG-23','Phone',90),
  ('2', 'AUG-23','Keypad',70),
  ('2', 'SEP-23','Laptop',120),
  ('2', 'SEP-23','Phone',30),
  ('2', 'SEP-23','Ipad',80),
  ('2', 'SEP-23','Keypad',40);
```

**Tried below PIVOT Query**

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT date, id,product, sum(product_cost)
     FROM product_info
     GROUP BY 1, 2,3
     ORDER BY 1, 2,3'
,
    'SELECT DISTINCT product FROM product_info ORDER BY 1'
) as cte(
    date text,
    id text, 
    "Ipad" numeric,
    "Keypad" numeric,
    "Laptop" numeric,
    "Phone" numeric
)
```

**RETURNED RESULT**

| date | id | Ipad | Keypad | Laptop | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUG-23 | 1 | NULL | 70 | 100 | 90 |
| SEP-23 | 1 | 80 | 40 | 120 | 30 |

I get a single row per month, with `id = '1'` and values for `id = '2'`.
I expected one row per ID.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

| id | date | Ipad | Keypad | Laptop | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AUG-23 | NULL | 50 | 100 | 80 |
| 2 | AUG-23 | NULL | 70 | 100 | 90 |
| 1 | SEP-23 | 150 | 80 | 200 | 100 |
| 2 | SEP-23 | 80 | 40 | 120 | 30 |

Comment: It would be helpful to present your table definition, and data as `INSERT` script. And proper date values in ISO format (`'2023-09-07'`). Or better, yet, add a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30). And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: Noted, thanks for suggestions

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Changed the question format, hope this is more clear

Comment: Yes, much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can use only obe row with crosstab, you can do something like this.

But simpler is a normal aggregation like the second query

```
SELECT split_part(id, '%', 1) as id,
  split_part(id, '%', 2) as date,
        "Ipad" ,
    "Laptop" ,
    "Phone" ,
    "Keypad" 
  FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT  CONCAT(id,''%'',date) as id, product, sum(cost)
     FROM product_info
     GROUP BY 1, 2
     ORDER BY 1, 2'
,
    'SELECT DISTINCT product FROM product_info ORDER BY 1'
) as cte(
    id text,
    "Ipad" numeric,
    "Laptop" numeric,
    "Phone" numeric,
    "Keypad" numeric
)
```

| id | date | Ipad | Laptop | Phone | Keypad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aug-23 | *null* | 50 | 250 | 100 |
| 1 | Sep-23 | 200 | 60 | 260 | 100 |
| 2 | Aug-23 | *null* | 80 | 220 | 100 |
| 2 | Sep-23 | 90 | 80 | 100 | 100 |

```
SELECT
  id,date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'Ipad' THEN cost END ) as "Ipad",
  SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'Laptop' THEN cost END ) as "Laptop",
  SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'Phone' THEN cost END ) as "Phone",
  SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'Keypad' THEN cost END ) as "Keypad"
FROM 
product_info
GROUP BY id,date
ORDER BY id,date
```

| id | date | Ipad | Laptop | Phone | Keypad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Aug-23 | *null* | 250 | 100 | 50 |
| 1 | Sep-23 | 200 | 260 | 100 | 60 |
| 2 | Aug-23 | *null* | 220 | 100 | 80 |
| 2 | Sep-23 | 90 | 100 | 100 | 80 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W8m-NheO)

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Just one question did you happen to change any of the values in the insert?
The returned values for product look higher than the expected result

Comment: i took your old values , with your new data https://dbfiddle.uk/HzT_bKdw

Comment: Case statements in the fiddle work like a charm
Thanks @nbk

Answer (score 0):

#### Proper `crosstab()` call

Quoting [the manual for `crosstab()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.52.5.7):

> `source_sql` is an SQL statement that produces the source set of data.
> This statement must return one `row_name` column, one `category`
> column, and one `value` column. It may also have one or more “extra”
> columns. The `row_name` column must be first. The `category` and
> `value` columns must be the last two columns, in that order. Any
> columns between `row_name` and `category` are treated as “extra”. The
> “extra” columns are expected to be the same for all rows with the same
> `row_name` value.

Your query does not produce data in the expected form:

```
row_name | extra ... | category | value
```

This query does:

```sql
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY date, id) AS rn  -- row_name
     , to_char(date, 'MON-YY') AS date, id          -- extra
     , product                                      -- category
     , sum(product_cost) AS sum_cost                -- value
FROM   product_info
GROUP  BY date, id, product
ORDER  BY date, id, product;
```

Your "row name" is a composite of `(date, id)`. (Simply concatenating could produce ambiguous results.) Generate a single-column `row_name` with the window function `dense_rank()` as demonstrated. `date` and `id` can be passed as "extra" columns.

Also, a `SELECT` query that generates category names dynamically rarely makes sense, since the static (!) column definition list has to match.

The query is based off an actual `date` column. Don't store date information as `text`, which does not sort properly.

This `crosstab()` call works:

```sql
-- CREATE TABLE pivot_test AS (
SELECT date, id, "Ipad", "Keypad", "Laptop", "Phone" 
FROM   crosstab(
   $q$
   SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY date, id)
        , to_char(date, 'MON-YY'), id
        , product
        , sum(product_cost)
   FROM   product_info
   GROUP  BY date, id, product
   ORDER  BY date, id, product
   $q$

,  $v$
   SELECT unnest('{Ipad, Keypad,Laptop, Phone}'::text[])
   $v$
   ) AS ct(rn int, date text, id int
         , "Ipad"   int
         , "Keypad" int
         , "Laptop" int
         , "Phone"  int);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DmwJVokm)

See:

- [Transpose latest rows per user to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/transpose-latest-rows-per-user-to-columns/23061730#23061730)
- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)
- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

#### Plain SQL

Typically, `crosstab()` is the fastest option. But for only few products, and since this case requires aggregation and a window function anyway, plain SQL may be even faster.

```sql
SELECT to_char(date, 'MON-YY') AS date, id
     , SUM(product_cost) FILTER (WHERE product = 'Ipad')   AS "Ipad"
     , SUM(product_cost) FILTER (WHERE product = 'Keypad') AS "Keypad"
     , SUM(product_cost) FILTER (WHERE product = 'Laptop') AS "Laptop"
     , SUM(product_cost) FILTER (WHERE product = 'Phone')  AS "Phone"
FROM   product_info
GROUP  BY date, id
ORDER  BY date, id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DmwJVokm)

See:

- [Sum by month and put months as columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598112/sum-by-month-and-put-months-as-columns/16598510#16598510)
- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)