# Pivot a table efficiently with short code

Tags: database, postgresql, pivot-table

I decided to do it manually, but I am only using a small chunk of the data. I am worried that when i send it to my team with the bigger table, they will have to add way more statements which would render my work useless

As you can see from my query, I am repeating the same statements over and over again only changing the id. is there a function i can create?

This is my query:

```
select
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "example_id",
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id  = 0 THEN example_name END) AS "example_name ",
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id = 0 AND type = 'data' THEN type END) AS "data",
    
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "example_id ",
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id = 2 THEN example_name END) AS "example_name ",
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id = 2 AND type = 'data' THEN type END) AS "data",
    
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "example_id ",
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id = 3 THEN example_name END) AS "example_name  ",
    MAX(CASE WHEN example_id = 3 AND type = 'data' THEN type END) AS "data",
from
    table

group by
    id;
```

Comment: If you want to pivot rows into columns that's a common way to to it. you can ditch `else 0`

Comment: Why don't you group by example_id as well? Instead of using a CASE you could also use FILTER, but that's just a preference in how to write the SQL statement.

Comment: There are various *much* simpler ways. But provide a proper setup with `CREATE TABLE` statement and data as `INSERT` statement, show your desired result and your Postgres version. Ideally, add a fiddle. Random example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598510/939860 and https://dbfiddle.uk/CByRvUei

Comment: Use Dynamic SQL to assemble a query that is based on the existing/changing data. Then run it.