# Selecting multiple max() values using a single SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table that has data that looks something like this:

```
data_type, value
World of Warcraft, 500
Quake 3, 1500
Quake 3, 1400
World of Warcraft, 1200
Final Fantasy, 100
Final Fantasy, 500
```

What I want to do is select the maximum of each of these values in a single statement. I know I can easily do something like

```
select data_type, max(value)
from table
where data_type = [insert each data type here for separate queries]
group by data_type
```

But what I want it to display is is

```
select data_type, 
  max(value) as 'World of Warcraft', 
  max(value) as 'Quake 3', 
  max(value) as 'Final Fantasy'
```

So I get the max value of each of these in a single statement. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So what's this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: Your presented preliminary solution *is* a single statement. You mean a single result *row*? If so, do you have a fixed number of 3 types, or are there more, possibly dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return the max value for each data_type in a separate column, then you should be able to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select
  max(case when data_type='World of Warcraft' then value end) WorldofWarcraft,
  max(case when data_type='Quake 3' then value end) Quake3,
  max(case when data_type='Final Fantasy' then value end) FinalFantasy
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/096e7/2)

Comment: Thank you it worked! I was using

>max(case when data_type='World of Warcraft' then max(value) end)

which didn't work, didn't think to get rid of the max in the inner part, thanks alot!

Comment: @user2146933 Glad it worked.  You were close, you can't nest aggregate functions like that. :)

Comment: As a quick question and thought, would it be possible to do this based on the most RECENT entry as opposed to the maximum entry?

Comment: @user2146933 How do you determine what is most recent?  Do you have a datetime or id value?  My suggestion is if you have different requirements to post a new question.

Comment: there is a datetime column also associated with it, but if it is too much different i could ask on a different question

Comment: @user2146933 I would post a new question with the details about your data and then the final result that you want, it would be easier then going back and forth in the comments. :)

Comment: +1 Right on target. But guess what: I am suggesting `crosstab()` yet again. This time with a "1-size-fits-all" bullet. :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Of course you come along with a `crosstab` answer! :) It was initially tagged with mysql as well so I gave a generic version.

Comment: @bluefeet: .. and there's nothing wrong with it. All the more, since the OP is not all that clear what he needs exactly.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I guess I need to still try and spend some time learning some postgresql! :)  But work is getting in my way.

Answer (score 6):

Once again, for more than just a few "data types", I suggest to use `crosstab()`:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
              'max' AS "type", data_type, val
       FROM   tbl
       ORDER  BY 1, 2, val DESC$$

    ,$$VALUES ('Final Fantasy'), ('Quake 3'), ('World of Warcraft')$$)
AS x ("type" text, "Final Fantasy" int, "Quake 3" int, "World of Warcraft" int)
```

Returns:

```
type | Final Fantasy | Quake 3 | World of Warcraft
-----+---------------+---------+-------------------
max  | 500           | 1500    |    1200
```

More explanation for the basics:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

### Dynamic solution

The tricky thing is to make this *completely dynamic*: to make it work for

- an **unknown number** of columns (data_types in this case)
- with **unknown names**  (data_types again)

At least the *type* is well known: `integer` in this case.

In short: that's not possible with current PostgreSQL (including 9.3). There are [approximations with polymorphic types and ways to circumvent the restrictions with arrays or hstore types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc). May be good enough for you. But it's *strictly not possible* to get the result with individual columns in a single SQL query. SQL is very rigid about types and wants to know what to expect back.

**However**, it can be done with *two* queries. The first one builds the actual query to use. Building on the above simple case:

```
SELECT $f$SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
              'max' AS "type", data_type, val
       FROM   tbl
       ORDER  BY 1, 2, val DESC$$

    ,$$VALUES ($f$     || string_agg(quote_literal(data_type), '), (') || $f$)$$)
AS x ("type" text, $f$ || string_agg(quote_ident(data_type), ' int, ') || ' int)'
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT data_type FROM tbl) x
```

This generates the query you actually need. Run the second one inside the *same transaction* to avoid concurrency issues.

Note the strategic use of [`quote_literal()` and `quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to sanitize all kinds of illegal (for columns) names and prevent *SQL injection*.

Don't get confused by multiple layers of [dollar-quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING). That's necessary for building dynamic queries. I put it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data to be aggregated in single string, go with bluefeet example, if you need a recordset with a record for each type:

```
select
    data_type,
    max(value) as value
from table1
group by data_type
```