# selecting multiple recent values in a single sql statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that has data that looks something like this:

```
data_type, value, datetime
World of Warcraft, 500, 2012-12-02
Quake 3, 1500, 2013-12-02
Quake 3, 1400, 2013-02-04
World of Warcraft, 1200, 2013-05-20
Final Fantasy, 100, 2013-02-03
Final Fantasy, 500, 2013-03-05
```

What I want to select is something like the following:

```
data_type, value
World of Warcraft, 1200
Quake 3, 1500
Final Fantasy, 500
```

```
select  
  most recent value for 'World of Warcraft', 
  most recent value for 'Quake 3', 
  most recent value for 'Final Fantasy'
```

So I get the most recent value of each of these in a single statement rather than having to separate them out. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple Max() values using a single SQL Statement - postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494829/selecting-multiple-max-values-using-a-single-sql-statement-postgresql)

Comment: i did not, this one is asking about selecting the most recent where as the other is asking for the maximum value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494829/selecting-multiple-max-values-using-a-single-sql-statement-postgresql

If you read the comments the person who helped was the one who actually suggesting a new question. But thanks for the help....

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is actually a different question

Comment: @Lamak: I noticed. I just looked so identical to the other one...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I asked the user to post a new question because the requirements changed from the other one.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT  *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY data_type 
                                  ORDER BY datetimecol DESC) AS RN
        FROM YourTable) AS A
WHERE RN = 1
```

There is actually a function `last_value` on Postgresql, but I'm not familiar with it.

If you want the data to appear in columns, then you can use:

```
SELECT 
    max(case when data_type='World of Warcraft' then value end) WorldofWarcraft,
    max(case when data_type='Quake 3' then value end) Quake3,
    max(case when data_type='Final Fantasy' then value end) FinalFantasy
FROM (  SELECT  data_type, value, datetime, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY data_type 
                                  ORDER BY datetimecol DESC) AS RN
        FROM YourTable) AS A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I believe they want the results in separate columns as well, so you might want to pivot it. :)

Comment: @bluefeet Oh, didn't realize about that, since the first result set he posted was on different rows. But you are right that the pseudo query he posted hints to pivoting. Too much work, we need someone with more expertise on that :-)

Comment: Just trying to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Another case for **[`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)**. Much simpler and faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (data_type)
       data_type, value
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY data_type DESC, datetime DESC;
```

You can include or exclude any columns you like. More explanation and details:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

I use `data_type` **`DESC`**, since your example indicates you want descending order for your data types. Omit `DESC` if you don't care.

You should also normalize your data. Create a lookup table for your data types and only store the foreign key in your main table. [Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)