# PostgreSQL 9.3: Dynamic pivot table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, crosstab

I have a table called as matrix which contains two columns namely `cola` and `colb` as
shown below:

**Table**: matrix

```
create table matrix
(
cola varchar(10),
colb varchar(10)
);
```

**Insertion of rows**:

```
insert into matrix values('A1','B1'),('A2','B2'),('A3','B3'),('A4','B4'),
             ('A5','B5'),('A6','B6'),('A7','B7'),('A8','B8'),
             ('A9','B9'),('A10','B10'),('A11','B11'),('A12','B12'),
             ('A13','B13'),('A14','B14'),('A15','B15'),('A16','B16'),
             ('A17','B17'),('A18','B18'),('A19','B19'),('A20','B20'),
             ('A21','B21'),('A22','B22'),('A23','B23'),('A24','B24'),
             ('A25','B25'),('A26','B26'),('A27','B27'),('A28','B28'),
             ('A29','B29'),('A30','B30');
```

**Note**: I want to show the result in the form of matrix and count which columns belongs to each others and assign the values in the matrix for each column. I have just
added 30 records for just example but there may be thousands of records also. So I need 
to prepare a dynamic pivot table for that. The expected result as shown below.

**Expected Result**:

```
      A1        A2      A3      A4      A5      A6 ................ A30
      ------------------------------------------------------------------
B1 |  1         0       0       0       0       0                    0  
   |    
B2 |  0         1       0       0       0       0                    0
   |
B3 |  0         0       1       0       0       0                    0 
   |
B4 |  0         0       0       1       0       0                    0
   | 
B5 |  0         0       0       0       1       0                    0 
   | 
B6 |  0         0       0       0       0       1                    0
.  |
.  |
.  |
.  |
B30|  0         0       0       0       0        0                   1
```

Comment: You can have a play with the crosstab function and see if that works for you. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: @mlinth, Can you please explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `crosstab()` from the additional module [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html):

```
SELECT b
     , COALESCE(a1, 0) AS "A1"
     , COALESCE(a2, 0) AS "A2"
     , COALESCE(a3, 0) AS "A3"
     , ... -- all the way up to "A30"
FROM   crosstab(
         'SELECT colb, cola, 1 AS val FROM matrix
          ORDER  BY 1,2'
        , $$SELECT 'A'::text || g FROM generate_series(1,30) g$$
       ) AS t (b text
             , a1  int, a2  int, a3  int, a4  int, a5  int, a6  int
             , a7  int, a8  int, a9  int, a10 int, a11 int, a12 int
             , a13 int, a14 int, a15 int, a16 int, a17 int, a18 int
             , a19 int, a20 int, a21 int, a22 int, a23 int, a24 int
             , a25 int, a26 int, a27 int, a28 int, a29 int, a30 int);
```

If `NULL` instead of `0` works, too, it can be just `SELECT *` in the outer query.
Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

The special "difficulty" here: no actual "value". So add `1 AS val` as last column.

#### Unknown number of categories

A completely dynamic query (with unknown result type) is not possible in a single query. You need *two* queries. First build a statement like the above dynamically, then execute it. Details:

- [Selecting multiple max() values using a single SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494829/selecting-multiple-max-values-using-a-single-sql-statement/18499498#18499498)
- [PostgreSQL convert columns to rows? Transpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084503/postgresql-convert-columns-to-rows-transpose/14087244#14087244)
- [Dynamically generate columns for crosstab in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879672/dynamically-generate-columns-for-crosstab-in-postgresql/12887645#12887645)
- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)

#### Too many categories

If you exceed the [maximum number of columns (1600)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606842/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-postgresql-select-query), a classic crosstab is impossible, because the result cannot be represented with individual columns. (Also, human eyes would hardly be able to read a table with that many columns)

Arrays or document types like [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html) or [`jsonb`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-json.html) are the alternative. Here is a solution with arrays:

```
SELECT colb, array_agg(cola) AS colas
FROM  (
   SELECT colb, right(colb, -1)::int AS sortb
        , CASE WHEN m.cola IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS cola
   FROM        (SELECT DISTINCT colb FROM matrix) b
   CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT cola FROM matrix) a
   LEFT   JOIN matrix m USING (colb, cola)
   ORDER  BY sortb, right(cola, -1)::int 
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1, sortb
ORDER  BY sortb;
```

- Build the complete grid of values with:

  ```
              (SELECT DISTINCT colb FROM matrix) b
  CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT cola FROM matrix) a
  ```
- `LEFT JOIN` existing combinations, order by the numeric part of the name and aggregate into arrays.

  - `right(colb, -1)::int` trims the leading character from 'A3' and casts the digits to integer so we get a proper sort order.

#### Basic matrix

If you just want a table of `0` an `1` where `x = y`, this can be had cheaper:

```
SELECT x, array_agg((x = y)::int) AS y_arr
FROM   generate_series(1,10) x
     , generate_series(1,10) y
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58df8/12) building on the one you provided in the comments.

Note that sqlfiddle.com currently has a bug that kills the display of array values. So I cast to `text` there to work around it.

Comment: @MAK: About "dynamic": That's *not possible* in a single query. You need two queries. First build the statement, then execute it. You are not the first to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334 Or you return arrays instead of individual columns. That *is* possible.

Comment: Okay! Let me try it out.

Comment: @MAK: Does that answer your question now?

Comment: Nope! Because I have 53000 records to show in a columns. Due to limit of columns `1600` I am unable to show in a pivot table.

Comment: The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334) which you have provided in your first comment in that the user is just looking for 3 columns that is `val1,val2,val3`. But here I have limitless columns.

Comment: I am getting an error near by second `ORDER` that is `ORDER BY right(cola, -1)::int`.

Comment: @MAK: Ah, sorry, that was `ORDER BY` twice. Added some improvements and a simple matrix while being at it.