# Add seconds into timestamp

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to add seconds into the given timestamp.

**Example**:

Given time:

```
Declare
       t1 timestamp = '1900-01-01 02:00:00';
```

Now I want to add some `20 seconds` into the given time.

In SQL Server I have used `DATEADD`. But I searched and come to know that there is no such function provided by PostgreSQL.

What will be the solution?

Comment: Just check the date/time operators: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Just add](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) the 20 seconds:

```
t1 := t1 + interval '20' second;
```

---

The assignment operator in PL/pgSQL is `:=`. The `=` is only there for backward compatibility. Don't use it.

Comment: Can you please help me for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337765/postgresql-9-3-dynamic-pivot-table