# How to reformat a dataset using the values of rows as new columns?

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab, data-analysis

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id | test_id
---+--------
1  | a
1  | b
1  | u 
2  | a 
2  | u 
3  | a 
3  | b 
3  | u
```

And I would like to roll it up into a new table such that the `test_id`'s are the column names (along with id) and the rows are either 1 or 0s depending if the test was given to that id, like so

```
id | a | b | u
---+---+---+--
1  | 1 | 1 | 1
2  | 1 | 0 | 1
3  | 1 | 1 | 1
```

Is there a way in Postgres that I can rearrange the table such as this?

Comment: Is the number of different items in `test_id` fixed or can there be other items too?

Comment: the `test_id` items are fixed.  There are actually about 30 test items. But every id may not have 30 associated `test_id`s

Comment: If an id don't have an associated test_id they would get 0 in my answer.

Comment: yes.  thank you and that works great.  Is there a way that counts them?  It turns out that some of the test_ids repeat for a given customer. Meaning a customer has tested twice on a particular `test_id`.  If zero, add one.  If one, add one again (2), etc.

Comment: If you want to count the number of times a customer has taken each test just change the `max()` to `sum()`. That would assign 0 to those who haven't taken the test and N (the number of times a test was taken). See this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/59c3f/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of possible `test_id` is fixed and known the easiest way to do this is to use conditional expressions like this:

```
select 
    id, 
    max(case when test_id = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as a,
    max(case when test_id = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) as b,
    max(case when test_id = 'u' then 1 else 0 end) as u
from your_table
group by id
order by id
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c0270/1)

If the `test_id` values are unknown and can vary then you need to use dynamic sql to generate the query.

Answer (score 1):

The actual crosstab ("pivot") solution for a given set of `test_id`'s:

```
SELECT id
     , COALESCE(a, 0) AS a
     , COALESCE(b, 0) AS b
     , COALESCE(u, 0) AS u
FROM   crosstab('SELECT id, test_id, 1 AS val FROM tbl ORDER BY 1,2'
              , $$VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('u')$$
       ) AS t (id int, a int, b int, u int);
```

For a dynamic set of `test_id`'s you need to build the statement in a first query and execute it in a second query. Or you return arrays instead.

Similar to this one:

- [PostgreSQL 9.3: Dynamic pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337765/postgresql-9-3-dynamic-pivot-table/29011847#29011847)

Basics about `crosstab()` (**read this** if you are new to it!):

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Alternatives:

- [Conditional SQL count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020065/conditional-sql-count/29022738#29022738)

Comment: This looks like it would work but the only caveat is I can't use crosstab() on the db I am using.

Comment: @aubonphysics: Consider my last link for shorter or new syntax in pg 9.4 without `crosstab()`.

Comment: I will take a look at it and get back to you.  Thanks.