# PostgreSQL 9.3: Display result in specific format using array_agg function

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.3

I want to show the given records in the following table into the specific format 
which is shown below in the table.

Creating table: `Test_1`

```
CREATE TABLE Test_1
(
ColumnA varchar,
ColumnB varchar
);
```

Insertion of records:

```
INSERT INTO Test_1 values('A101','B101'),('A102','B102'),
            ('A103','B103'),('A104','B104'),
            ('A105','B105'),('A106','B106'),
            ('A107','B107'),('A108','B108'),
            ('A109','B109'),('A201','B201');
```

I want to show the result like this:

**Expected Result**:

```
ColumnA     ColumnX
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A101        "B101" =  1, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 0
A102        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 1, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 0
A103        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 1, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 0
A104        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 1, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 0
A105        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 1, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 0
A106        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 1, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 0
A107        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 1, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 0
A108        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 1, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 0
A109        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 1, "B201" = 0
A201        "B101" =  0, "B102" = 0, "B103" = 0, "B104" = 0, "B105" = 0, "B106" = 0, "B107" = 0, "B108" = 0, "B109" = 0, "B201" = 1
```

For which I am using the following script which does my half job:

```
SELECT columnA, array_agg(ColumnB) AS ColumnX
FROM  (
   SELECT ColumnA, right(ColumnA, -1)::int AS sortb
    , CASE WHEN m.ColumnB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ColumnB
   FROM        (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA FROM Test_1) b
   CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnB FROM Test_1) a
   LEFT   JOIN Test_1 m USING (ColumnA, ColumnB)
   ORDER  BY sortb, right(ColumnB, -1)::int 
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1, sortb
ORDER  BY sortb;
```

The above script gives me the following result:

**Getting result**:

```
ColumnA          ColumnX
---------------------------------------
A101        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
A102        {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
A103        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
A104        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}
A105        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}
A106        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0}
A107        {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0}
A108        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0}
A109        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0}
A201        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
```

Question: How to add `columnB` values infront of values of getting in `ColumnX`?

Comment: Does this [output](http://pastie.org/10051659) is acceptable ??

Comment: @unique_id, Yup! Why not. This is more readable.

Comment: So test [this](http://pastie.org/10051672),If worked then I'll Post it as Answer  :)

Comment: @unique_id, Almost done. Only the change is, if I insert same record for example `('A101','B101')` two times then it has to show me `B101= 2`. In your case it is show like `B101=1 , B101=1`.

Comment: This is a follow-up to this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337765/postgresql-9-3-dynamic-pivot-table/29011847

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter, Yup! Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a simple modification.
Also added the actual count as requested in your comment.

```
SELECT columnA, array_agg(ColumnB) AS ColumnX
FROM  (
   SELECT ColumnA, right(ColumnA, -1)::int AS sorta
        , '"' || ColumnB || '" = ' || count(m.ColumnB) AS ColumnB
   FROM        (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA FROM Test_1) b
   CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnB FROM Test_1) a
   LEFT   JOIN Test_1 m USING (ColumnA, ColumnB)
   GROUP  BY ColumnA, ColumnB
   ORDER  BY sorta, right(ColumnB, -1)::int 
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1, sorta
ORDER  BY sorta;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bc598/2)

#### One array

As per comment:

```
SELECT ARRAY[columnA] || array_agg(ColumnB) AS ColumnX
FROM  (
   SELECT ColumnA, right(ColumnA, -1)::int AS sorta
        , '"' || ColumnB || '" = ' || count(m.ColumnB) AS ColumnB
   FROM        (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA FROM Test_1) b
   CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnB FROM Test_1) a
   LEFT   JOIN Test_1 m USING (ColumnA, ColumnB)
   GROUP  BY ColumnA, ColumnB
   ORDER  BY right(ColumnB, -1)::int, sorta
   ) sub
GROUP  BY columnA, sorta
ORDER  BY sorta;
```

Comment: Almost done. Only the change is, if I insert same record for example `('A101','B101')` two times then it has to showing me `B101= 2`. In your case it is show like `B101=1 , B101=1`.

Comment: Only need to edit in your answer is: add `m.ColumnB` into the `GROUP BY`. Well! that is understandable.

Comment: @MAK: No, this is better. Use `ColumnB` in the expression without table qualification (which was wrong).

Comment: Can I able to union both columns `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` and display in the `ColumnX`?

Comment: @MAK: I added a query. Also changed the column alias "sortb" to "sorta".

Comment: I want to union `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` values like :`A101=0, A102=0, A103=0.........B101=1,B102=0,B1-3=0`.

Comment: @MAK: I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Here is the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293033/postgresql-9-3-union-two-columns-in-one).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columnA, array_agg(ColumnB) AS ColumnX
FROM  (
  SELECT ColumnA, right(ColumnA, -1)::int AS sortb
    , CASE WHEN m.ColumnB IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE m.ColumnB||'='||( count(m.ColumnB)) END AS ColumnB
   FROM        (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA FROM Test_1) b
   CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnB FROM Test_1) a
   LEFT   JOIN Test_1 m USING (ColumnA, ColumnB)
 group by ColumnA,m.ColumnB,ColumnB
   ORDER  BY sortb, right(ColumnB, -1)::int 

   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1, sortb
ORDER  BY sortb;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But according to FIFO I suppose to accept Erwin's answer. Sorry for that :(

Comment: @MAK It Doesn't Matter :)

Comment: Thanks, but +1 for sure.