# Rearrange PSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table that looks like this

```
------------------------
 Letter | Status | Count
 A      | active | 3
 A      | offline| 1
 B      | active | 12
 B      | offline| 3
 C      | fixing | 4
 C      | active | 2
```

How can I make it looks like this

```
-----------------------------------
 Letter | active | offline | fixing
 A      | 3      | 1       | 0
 B      | 12     | 3       | 0
 C      | 2      | 0       | 4
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Dynamic Pivot several examples on Site already!  Here's [One example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337765/postgresql-9-3-dynamic-pivot-table) and a [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087948/dynamic-pivot-query-using-postgresql-9-3)  though it's unclear if you want a query or if you really want to change the table structure.

Comment: @xQbert both examples are not truly "dynamic" because them requires hardcoded resultset structure. BTW.

Comment: Perhaps this is a better example then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`crosstab()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) for this case:

```
-- DDL and data
CREATE TABLE old (
  letter TEXT,
  status TEXT,
  status_count INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO old VALUES
  ('A','active',3),
  ('A','offline',1),
  ('B','active',12),
  ('B','offline',3),
  ('C','fixing',4),
  ('C','active',2);
-- add crosstab function
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;

CREATE TABLE new_table AS (
  SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT * FROM old ORDER BY 1,2',
  'SELECT DISTINCT status FROM old ORDER BY 1'
  ) AS new_table(letter TEXT,active INTEGER,fixing INTEGER,offline INTEGER)
);
-- validate
SELECT * FROM new_table;
```

Result:

```
 letter | active | fixing | offline 
--------+--------+--------+---------
 A      |      3 |        |       1
 B      |     12 |        |       3
 C      |      2 |      4 |        
(3 rows)
```