# Merge rows into single row Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to merge two rows.
Currently my table looks something like this -

| equipment_number | etd | eta | atd | ata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MAHE8346461 | 2023-02-03 10:02:00 | 2023-01-03 10:02:00 | null | null |
| MAHE8346461 | null | null | 2022-02-03 10:02:00 | null |
| MAHE8346462 | null | 2022-02-04 13:02:00 | null | 2022-02-04 13:02:00 |
| MAHE8346462 | 2022-02-04 13:02:00 | 2022-02-04 13:02:00 | 2022-02-03 10:02:00 | null |
| MAHE8346462 | null | 2022-02-04 13:02:00 | null | null |

the resultant output expected is -

| equipment_number | etd | eta | atd | ata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MAHE8346461 | 2023-02-03 10:02:00 | 2023-01-03 10:02:00 | 2022-02-03 10:02:00 | null |
| MAHE8346462 | 2022-02-04 13:02:00 | 2023-01-03 10:02:00 | 2022-02-03 10:02:00 | 2022-02-04 13:02:00 |

so I need to combine/merge the multiple rows with same equipment_number into one to reduce the row numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres pivot without crosstab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511104/postgres-pivot-without-crosstab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do so by using `group by` and the aggregation function `max()` or `min()` depending on whether you want to keep the oldest or the newest records.

```
select equipment_number, max(etd) as etd,  max(eta) as eta,  max(atd) as atd,  max(ata) as ata
from mytable
group by equipment_number
order by equipment_number
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GLcRkeIR)