# PostgreSQL 9.3: Filter in Pivot table query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, postgresql-9.3

Well I have this records:

```
  Employee_Number    Employee_role         Group_Name
  ----------------------------------------------------
  EMP101             C# Developer            Group_1      
  EMP102             ASP Developer           Group_1      
  EMP103             SQL Developer           Group_2      
  EMP104             PLSQL Developer         Group_2      
  EMP101             Java Developer          
  EMP102             Web Developer          
  EMP101             DBA          
  EMP105             DBA          
  EMP106             SQL Developer           Group_3      
  EMP107             Oracle Developer        Group_3      
  EMP101             Oracle Developer        Group_3
```

Want to show the pivot table for above records in the following format:

```
 Employee_Number     TotalRoles      TotalGroups       Available     Others     Group_1     Group_2      Group_3
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 EMP101                   4               3                2            2          1                        1
 EMP102                   2               3                1            1          1 
 EMP103                   1               3                1            0                      1
 EMP104                   1               3                1            0                      1
 EMP105                   1               3                0            1
 EMP106                   1               3                1            0                                   1
 EMP107                   1               3                1            0                                   1
```

For the above result I am using the following script:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
      $$SELECT grp.*, e.group_name
         , CASE WHEN e.employee_number IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS val
    FROM  (
       SELECT employee_number
        , count(employee_role)::int            AS total_roles
        , (SELECT count(DISTINCT group_name)::int
           FROM   employee
           WHERE  group_name <> '')            AS total_groups
        , count(group_name <> '' OR NULL)::INT AS available                    
        , count(group_name =  '' OR NULL)::int AS others
       FROM   employee
       GROUP  BY employee_number
       ) grp
    LEFT   JOIN employee e ON e.employee_number = grp.employee_number
                  AND e.group_name <> ''         
    ORDER  BY grp.employee_number, e.group_name$$
     ,$$VALUES ('Group_1'),('Group_2'),('Group_3')$$
   ) AS ct (employee_number text
      , total_roles  int
      , total_groups int
      , available    int
      , others       int
      , "Group_1"    int
      , "Group_2"    int
      , "Group_3"    int);
```

**But**:Now I want to show the pivot table for the above records by **filtering** the `Group_Name`.
That means if I want to show the pivot table for the only `Group_Name= Group_3` then it has
to show only the employee who is only belongs to the `Group_Name= Group_3` not other than that.

If I want to see the employee who is belongs to the `Group_3` only than it has to show me:

```
   Employee_Number    total_roles  total_groups   available    others    Group_3
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
       EMP106             1             3            1            0            1
       EMP107             1             3            1            0            1
```

**Note**: As you can see in the first table the employee `EMP106` and `EMP107` is only belongs 
to the `Group_Name = Group_3`. The employee `EMP101` is also belong but he also belongs to other groups 
so should not appear in this table.

Comment: You are mixing `Group_1` and `Group_3` in the example. The note clarifies your intention.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter, Yup! Done with the editing.

Comment: So, `total_roles`, `total_groups` etc. should still be based on the whole table (including other groups)? It seems clear for `total_groups`, but not for the rest.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter, Yes. The `total_roles`,`total_groups`,`others` will be same based on the whole table except `available`. The `available` is only getting changes.

Comment: I don't see how `available` would change. Since there are no other groups for the selected rows, it should be the same in either query, right?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter, Oh! yeah. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can `group_name` be NULL? Or are the empty spots in the source table actually empty strings (`''`)?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter, It's a empty string `('')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to exclude the offending rows:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

The `crosstab()` query adapted:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    $$SELECT grp.*, e.group_name
           , CASE WHEN e.employee_number IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS val
      FROM  (
         SELECT employee_number
              , count(employee_role)::int            AS total_roles
              , (SELECT count(DISTINCT group_name)::int
                 FROM   employee
                 WHERE  group_name <> '')            AS total_groups
              , count(group_name <> '' OR NULL)::int AS available
              , count(group_name = '' OR NULL)::int  AS others
         FROM   employee
         GROUP  BY employee_number
         ) grp
      JOIN   employee e USING (employee_number)
      WHERE  e.group_name = 'Group_3'
      AND    NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM employee
         WHERE  employee_number = e.employee_number
         AND    group_name  e.group_name
         )
      ORDER  BY employee_number$$
   ,$$VALUES ('Group_3')$$
   ) AS ct (employee_number text
      , total_roles  int
      , total_groups int
      , available    int
      , others       int
      , "Group_3"    int);
```

But as you can see, we don't need `crosstab()` here at all. Simplify to:

```
SELECT grp.*, 1 AS "Group_3"
FROM  (
   SELECT employee_number
        , count(employee_role)::int            AS total_roles
        , (SELECT count(DISTINCT group_name)::int
           FROM   employee
           WHERE  group_name <> '')            AS total_groups
        , count(group_name <> '' OR NULL)::int AS available
        , count(group_name = '' OR NULL)::int  AS others
   FROM   employee
   GROUP  BY employee_number
   ) grp
JOIN   employee e USING (employee_number)
WHERE  e.group_name = 'Group_3'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM employee
   WHERE  employee_number = e.employee_number
   AND    group_name <> e.group_name
   )
ORDER  BY employee_number;
```

The column `"Group_3"` is really just noise here, because it is always `1` by definition.

If only a small percentage of rows is selected this way, this version with a `LATERAL` join should be substantially faster:

```
SELECT e.employee_number
     , grp.total_roles
     , total.total_groups
     , grp.available
     , grp.others
     , 1 AS "Group_3"
FROM  (
   SELECT employee_number
   FROM   employee e
   WHERE  group_name = 'Group_3'
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM employee
      WHERE  employee_number = e.employee_number
      AND    group_name <> e.group_name
      )
   ) e
, LATERAL (
   SELECT count(employee_role)::int            AS total_roles
        , count(group_name <> '' OR NULL)::int AS available
        , count(group_name = '' OR NULL)::int  AS others
   FROM   employee
   WHERE  employee_number = e.employee_number
   GROUP  BY employee_number
   ) grp
,    (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT group_name)::int AS total_groups
   FROM   employee
   WHERE  group_name <> ''
   ) total
ORDER  BY employee_number;
```

Details for the `LATERAL` solution and performance:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

#### Simple, generic solution for any set of groups

Not optimized for performance, but easy to adapt:

```
<original crosstab query from your question>
WHERE  "Group_3" = 1
AND    "Group_1" IS NULL
AND    "Group_2" IS NULL
AND    "Group_4" IS NULL
AND    others = 0  -- to rule out membership in the "empty" group
-- possibly more ...
```

Comment: The employee `EMP101` is also getting displayed with `EMP106` and `EMP107` whereas is it should not because he the `EMP101` is also belongs to other groups.

Comment: Again in the last script also I am getting `EMP101`.

Comment: If a new employee `EMP108` is add with two different groups 
`INSERT INTO employee values('EMP108','JSP','Group_4'),('EMP108','JS','Group_5')` the I want to filter the `Group_4` and `Group_5`. It has to show me the employee `EMP108` right?

Comment: @MAK: The solutions so far are tailored for a single group. I added a simple, generic solution for any set of groups.

Comment: There is still some work remaining. If I filter the `Group_name = Group_1` then according to the table it should not display any employee because of no one is **only** belongs to `Group_1`. But as per your simple,generic solution it's showing employee `EMP102` whereas he has 2 roles, you can see in the table.

Comment: @MAK: The second role of `EMP102` belongs to the empty group, which can be ruled out by checking `others = 0`.