# Query with dynamic target columns

Tags: postgresql, join, many-to-many, pivot, crosstab

I am trying to build a view in Postgres that uses 3 tables worth of data. I am not sure if this is possible and have searched around a bit on google but didn't turn up anything conclusive. This is what I am attempting to do:

I have a table of item names - lets say there are 5 items:

`fruits`

```
id | name
1  | banana
2  | orange
3  | pear
4  | apple
5  | grape
```

I then have a list of people

`people`

```
id  |  name
1   |  Joe Blow
2   |  Sally Smith
3   |  John Jones
4   |  Sam Benny
5   |  Nick Stevens
6   |  Peter Sandwitch
7   |  Sarah Morgan
```

I then have a third table linking the two above:

`people_fruits`

```
person_id | fruit_id
1         | 1
1         | 2
1         | 3
1         | 4
2         | 1
2         | 3
3         | 5
6         | 3
7         | 3
7         | 4
```

What I am trying to do is be able to dynamically create a view utilizing the above that will change the columns based on the content of the fruit table. for example, I would want the view to show the above data as follows:

`my_fruity_view`

```
name            | bananna | orange | pear | apple | grape
Joe Blow        | X       | X      | X    | X     |
Sally Smith     | X       |        | X    |       |
John Jones      |         |        |      |       | X
Sam Benny       |         |        |      |       |
Nick Stevens    |         |        |      |       |
Peter Sandwitch |         |        | X    |       |
Sarah Morgan    |         |        | X    | X     |
```

Then if I was to add the fruit mango at a later time, the next time the query was run (without modification), it would add that as a column:

`my_fruity_view`

```
name            | bananna | orange | pear | apple | grape | mango
Joe Blow        | X       | X      | X    | X     |       |
Sally Smith     | X       |        | X    |       |       |
John Jones      |         |        |      |       | X     |
Sam Benny       |         |        |      |       |       |
Nick Stevens    |         |        |      |       |       |
Peter Sandwitch |         |        | X    |       |       |
Sarah Morgan    |         |        | X    | X     |       |
```

Is such a query possible? I see a few things like this on stack overflow - but it seems like its done on a per column basis - but my data needs to be dynamic.

I can achieve this with programming but I would much prefer to pack it up into a view to keep things neat. any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of apologizing for the formatting, why don't you just format things properly?

Comment: Friendly instructions how to format here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Your question doesn't look that bad, though, we have seen *much* worse.

Comment: Thank you, noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want a **pivot** table or a **cross tabulation**. The additional module `tablefunc` provides the functionality you need. If you are not familiar with it, read this first:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

The special difficulty of your case: you first need a query joining the tables to produce the right input:

```
SELECT p.name, f.name, text 'x' AS marker -- required, logically redundant column
FROM   people             p
LEFT   JOIN people_fruits pf ON pf.person_id = p.id  -- LEFT JOIN !
LEFT   JOIN fruits        f  ON f.id = pf.fruit_id
ORDER  BY p.id, f.id;  -- seems to be the desired sort order
```

`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, so you don't lose people without fruits.

Use it in a `crosstab()` function taking *two* parameters like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    $$SELECT p.name, f.name, text 'x'
      FROM   people             p
      LEFT   JOIN people_fruits pf ON pf.person_id = p.id
      LEFT   JOIN fruits        f  ON f.id = pf.fruit_id
      ORDER  BY p.id$$   
   ,$$VALUES ('bananna'), ('orange'), ('pear'), ('apple'), ('grape')$$)
AS ct (name text, bananna text, orange text, pear text, apple text, grape text);
```

The order of fruits in the target column list has to match the order of fruits in the 2nd parameter (ordered by `id` in your case).

Missing fruits get a `NULL` value.

However, this is not **dynamic**, yet. Completely dynamic is strictly not possible with SQL, which requires to know resulting columns at call time. One way or the other, you need two round trips to the DB server. You can let Postgres build the crosstab query dynamically and then execute it in the next step.

Related answers with code examples:

- [Execute a dynamic crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804551/execute-a-dynamic-crosstab-query/36831103#36831103)
- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#1551433)

An **alternative** would be to return an array or a document type (`json`, `xml`, ...) that *contains* a dynamic list of elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Erwin - this is simple and informative. and I can see how either doing "two round trips" as you put it or returning some json or xml would be the way to go. I am going to attempt to implement this by returning the column names back to my application, parsing them into the field names as per the format above and running the new query with the parsed column names included.

Comment: Ok - I had a go at this and came up with an initial formatting query that builds the two sets of column names as per your example above: 
`select
string_agg(
 concat('(''', name, ''')'), ', ' order by name 
) as fruit_columns
from
fruits
union
select
concat( 'name text, ',
 string_agg(
  concat(name, ' text'), ', ' order by name 
 )
) as fruit_columns
from
fruits`

This is then passed to my app and used to build the full query based on your answer above. From there I can get the exact format I am after!!