# Postgres table transformation: transposing values of a column into new columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose, crosstab

Is there a way to transpose/flatten the following table -

| userId | time window | propertyId | count | sum | avg | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01:00 - 02:00 | a | 2 | 5 | 1.5 | 3 |
| 1 | 02:00 - 03:00 | a | 4 | 15 | 2.5 | 6 |
| 1 | 01:00 - 02:00 | b | 2 | 5 | 1.5 | 3 |
| 1 | 02:00 - 03:00 | b | 4 | 15 | 2.5 | 6 |
| 2 | 01:00 - 02:00 | a | 2 | 5 | 1.5 | 3 |
| 2 | 02:00 - 03:00 | a | 4 | 15 | 2.5 | 6 |
| 2 | 01:00 - 02:00 | b | 2 | 5 | 1.5 | 3 |
| 2 | 02:00 - 03:00 | b | 4 | 15 | 2.5 | 6 |

to something like this -

| userId | time window | a_count | a_sum | a_avg | a_max | b_count | b_sum | b_avg | b_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01:00 - 02:00 | 2 | 5 | 1.5 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 1.5 | 3 |
| 1 | 02:00 - 03:00 | 4 | 15 | 2.5 | 6 | 4 | 15 | 2.5 | 6 |
| 2 | 01:00 - 02:00 | 2 | 5 | 1.5 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 1.5 | 3 |
| 2 | 02:00 - 03:00 | 4 | 15 | 2.5 | 6 | 4 | 15 | 2.5 | 6 |

Basically, I want to flatten the table by having the aggregation columns (count, sum, avg, max) per propertyId, so the new columns are a_count, a_sum, a_avg, a_max, b_count, b_sum, ... All the rows have these values per userId per time window.

Important clarification: The values in propertyId column can change and hence, the number of columns can change as well. So, if there are n different values for propertyId, then there will be n*4 aggregation columns created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Comment: I checked this link out, but, it doesn't suit my case as the number of propertyId values is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not allow a dynamic number of result columns on principal. It demands to know number and data types of resulting columns at call time. The only way to make it "dynamic" is a two-step process:

1. Generate the query.
2. Execute it.

If you don't actually need separate columns, returning arrays or document-type columns (`json`, `jsonb`, `xml`, `hstore`, ...) *containing* a variable number of data sets would be a feasible alternative.

See:

- [Execute a dynamic crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804551/execute-a-dynamic-crosstab-query/36831103#36831103)

Comment: Thank you @ErwinBrandstetter. I am using dbt and jinja templating to generate the query indeed.