# Postgres values as columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I am working with PostgreSQL 9.3, and I have this:

#### PARENT_TABLE

```
ID | NAME
1  | N_A
2  | N_B
3  | N_C
```

#### CHILD_TABLE

```
ID | PARENT_TABLE_ID | KEY | VALUE
1  | 1               | K_A | V_A
2  | 1               | K_B | V_B
3  | 1               | K_C | V_C
5  | 2               | K_A | V_D
6  | 2               | K_C | V_E
7  | 3               | K_A | V_F
8  | 3               | K_B | V_G
9  | 3               | K_C | V_H
```

Note that I might add K_D in KEY's, it's completely dynamic.

What I want is a query that returns me the following:

#### QUERY_TABLE

```
ID | NAME | K_A | K_B | K_C | others K_...
1  | N_A  | V_A | V_B | V_C | ...
2  | N_B  | V_D |     | V_E | ...
3  | N_C  | V_F | V_G | V_H | ...
```

Is this possible to do ? If so, how ?

Comment: `crosstab()` can be used for this. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: But I still need to specify the name of the columns in my query, right? If I have a child table with KEY_D, do I need to add that column to crosstab ?

Comment: Yes. You cannot ask for *whatever key in my child table, use that as a column*. The planner needs to know about the column count and each column's type.

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be values missing, you need the "safe" form of [`crosstab()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS) with the column names as second parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT p.id, p.name, c.key, c."value"
        FROM   parent_table p
        LEFT   JOIN child_table c ON c.parent_table_id = p.id
        ORDER  BY 1'

      ,$$VALUES ('K_A'::text), ('K_B'), ('K_C')$$)
AS t (id int, name text, k_a text, k_b text, k_c text;  -- use actual data types
```

Details in this related answer:
[PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

About adding "extra" columns:
[Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

Comment: The problem with this is that it's not dynamicly generated. But thank you.