# How to use Pivot in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I need to use pivot in postgres, below is the base table

[image]

Below is the desired output

[image]

Please help me with the query.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an un-pivot, not pivot

```
select year, week, 'loading' as area, loading as value
from the_table
union all
select year, week, 'picking', picking
from the_table
union all
select year, week, 'painting', painting
from the_table
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. saved me

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3 columns which you need to pivot, then use `union`

```
select year,week,'loading' as aread,loading as val from tbl
union all
select year,week,'painting' as area,painting as val from tbl
union all
select year,week,'picking' as area,picking as val from tbl
```

If the number of column is dynamic, then I 'd suggest you to use dynamic pivot.

[Dynamic pivot query using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087948/dynamic-pivot-query-using-postgresql-9-3)

http://www.cureffi.org/2013/03/19/automatically-creating-pivot-table-column-names-in-postgresql/