# Creating dynamic columns from table data

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, crosstab

Table data sample:

```
--------------------------
| key | domain | value   |
--------------------------
| a   | en     | English |
| a   | de     | Germany |
```

Query which returns result I need:

```
select * from 
(
    select t1.key,
        (select value from TABLE where t1.key=key AND code='en') en,
        (select value from TABLE where t1.key=key AND code='de') de
    from TABLE t1
) as t2
```

Data returned from query:

```
---------------------------
| key | en      | de      |
---------------------------
| a   | English | Germany |
```

I do not want to list all available domains with:

```
(select value from TABLE where t1.key=key AND code='*') *
```

Is it possible to make this query more dynamic in Postgres: automatically add all domain columns that exist in the table?

Comment: So you want all distinct non-null domain values as column names? You'll probably have to use dynamic sql in plpgsql and execute it with EXECUTE.

Comment: Dynamic number of columns? Plain SQL cannot do that, but pl/pgSQL could, as @eurotrash says.

Comment: [Dynamic pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087948/dynamic-pivot-query-using-postgresql-9-3#28149684)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more than a few domains use `crosstab()` to make the query shorter and faster.

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

A *completely* dynamic query, returning a dynamic number of columns based on data in your table is not possible, because SQL is strictly typed. Whatever you try, you'll end up needing two steps. Step 1: generate the query, step 2: execute it.

- [Execute a dynamic crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804551/execute-a-dynamic-crosstab-query/36831103#36831103)

Or you return something more flexible instead of table columns, like an array or a document type like `json`. Details:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)
- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)