# Dynamic columns in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE services (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE client_services (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    client_id integer NOT NULL,
    service_id integer NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO clients(id, name)
VALUES (1, 'Client 1'), 
       (2, 'Client 2');

INSERT INTO services(id, name)
VALUES (1, 'Service 1'), 
       (2, 'Service 2');       

INSERT INTO client_services(id, client_id, service_id)
VALUES (1, 1, 1),
       (2, 1, 2),
       (3, 2, 2);
```

and I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.name,
    COUNT(cs.id) FILTER(WHERE s.name = 'Service 1') AS "Service 1",
    COUNT(cs.id) FILTER(WHERE s.name = 'Service 2') AS "Service 2"
FROM
    clients c
INNER JOIN
    client_services cs ON cs.client_id = c.id
INNER JOIN 
    services s ON s.id = cs.service_id
GROUP BY
    c.name;
```

which returns this:

```
| name     | Service 1 | Service 2 |
| -------- | --------- | --------- |
| Client 1 | 1         | 1         |
| Client 2 | 0         | 1         |
```

Problem is that if I decide to add another service to `services` table I will need to update my query. Is there any way to make that part of the query dynamic:

```
COUNT(cs.id) FILTER(WHERE s.name = 'Service 1') AS "Service 1",
COUNT(cs.id) FILTER(WHERE s.name = 'Service 2') AS "Service 2"
```

EDIT:

I forgot to add link do sql fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mhcs7UBpW93fHoYqadNZMx/1

Comment: You should do that kind of formatting in your application, SQL isn't really good at that. How (where) exactly are you using the result of that query? If you are using that for display purposes, aggregating into a key/value structure (e.g. JSONB) might be a better option

Comment: Where is the end result supposed to be displayed?  Only query or in an application (web or other)?

Why not simply do something like:

SELECT DISTINCT
    c.id AS client_id,
    c.name AS client_name,
    s.id AS service_id,
    s.name AS service_name,
    count(*) AS client_service_count
FROM
    clients c
JOIN
    client_services cs ON cs.client_id = c.id
JOIN 
    services s ON s.id = cs.service_id
GROUP BY
    c.id,
    s.id
;

And then use the result in your display table?

Comment: If you want to have explicit 0 for client_service_count, then you will need to do a INNER JOIN services and LEFT JOIN client_services.

Comment: This query will be used for display purposes in my web application.

Comment: What you are trying to do is really a pivot table with dynamic columns. which is very difficult in SQL. As stated by others, if you are displaying this in a web application, a better approach is to do this logic on the application side in your code. For reference, here is a question regarding dynamic pivot tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087948/dynamic-pivot-query-using-postgresql-9-3

Comment: If you want to display the result in a web application, then a JSON aggregate is the more flexible way to do it in SQL.