# How to count when don't know specific types

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, dynamic-sql, crosstab

I'm working on a table kind of like this:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | C |
| 5 | C |

I wanted to count the number of ids for each type, and get a table like this.

| type_a | type_b | type_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

What I did was

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_b,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS type_c
FROM myTable
```

My question is, if I don't know how many types are there, and can't specificly list all cases, how can I achieve it?

Comment: It would have been much easier to return the result as two columns: Type, Count.

Comment: then you need to use dynamic sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic pivot query using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087948/dynamic-pivot-query-using-postgresql-9-3)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "cross tabulation" or a "pivot table". I added tags.
However:

> if I don't know how many types are there, and can't specifically list all cases, how can I achieve it?

**Basically**, that's **impossible** in a single SQL query because SQL demands to know the number of result columns at call time. It cannot return a dynamic number of columns on principle.

There are various workarounds with polymorphic types, or with a document type like `json`, `jsonb`, `hstore` or `xml`, or return arrays instead of individual columns ...

But to get exactly what you are asking for, an unknown number of dedicated columns, you need a two-step workflow. Like:

1. Build the query dynamically (determining the return type).
2. Execute it.

Related:

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

That said, if your case is **simple** and you deal with a **hand full of known types**, you can just **over-provision**. With a faster `crosstab()` query, or with simple conditional aggregation like you have it, just more elegant and efficient with the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 'A') AS type_a
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 'B') AS type_b
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 'C') AS type_c
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 'D') AS type_d
     -- that's all folks!
FROM   tbl;
```

Types with no entries report `0` (`count()` never returns `NULL`) which would be correct anyway.

Does not work for unknown types, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you want is a simple COUNT:

```
SELECT
    type
    ,COUNT(id)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: There are some more columns that I wants to add. For example:

count, percentage, etc. and would like this to be, for each column, it is a type, for the first row, it's the count of each type, and for the second row, it's the percentage of each type. (percentage = count of each type / total counts of id).