# How to pass dynamic values in query CASE expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

```sql
SELECT 
    req,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (stage='Selected') THEN count ELSE NULL END) AS selected,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (stage='Initial Selection') THEN count ELSE NULL END) AS "Initial Selection",
    SUM(CASE WHEN (stage='Hr Round') THEN count ELSE NULL END) AS "Hr Round"
FROM table1
GROUP BY req
;
```

In the above Postgres query, the value for `stage` is passed statically (hard-coded) in CASE expression, how can we pass the value for `stage` dynamically from the result of another query?

Comment: You might want to use `SUM(count) FILTER (WHERE stage = …)` instead of `CASE` expressions

Comment: Just use a subselect in place of the value you want to be dynamic.

Comment: If the number of columns you want returned by your query needs to change depending on the number of rows that some other table has, there is no good way to do that.  You will need to construct your query text dynamically then execute it.

Comment: Could it be that you are looking for is the pivoting?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087948/dynamic-pivot-query-using-postgresql-9-3

Comment: If you will add `stage` field to `group by`, then query will be returning the data as you wanted.