# How to generate multiple time series in one sql query?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

Here is the database layout. I have a table with sparse sales over time, aggregated per day. If for an item I have 10 sales on the 01-01-2015, I will have an entry, but If I have 0, then I have no entry. Something like this.

```
|--------------------------------------|
| day_of_year | year | sales | item_id |
|--------------------------------------|
|      01     | 2015 |  20   |   A1    |
|      01     | 2015 |  11   |   A2    | 
|      07     | 2015 |  09   |   A1    | 
|     ...     | ...  |  ...  |  ...    | 
|--------------------------------------|
```

This is how I get a time series for 1 item.

```
SELECT doy, max(sales) FROM (
    SELECT day_of_year AS doy,
           sales       AS sales
      FROM myschema.entry_daily
     WHERE item_id = theNameOfmyItem
       AND year = 2015
       AND day_of_year < 150
     UNION
    SELECT doy AS doy,
           0   AS sales
      FROM generate_series(1, 149) AS doy) as t
GROUP BY doy
ORDER BY doy;
```

And I currently loop with R making 1 query for every item. I then aggregate the results in a dataframe. But this is very slow. I would actually like to have only one query that would aggregate all the data in the following form.

```
|----------------------------------------------|
| item_id | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | ... | 149 |
|----------------------------------------------|
|    A1   | 10 | 00 | 00 | 05 | 12 | ... |  11 |
|    A2   | 11 | 00 | 30 | 01 | 15 | ... |  09 |
|    A3   | 20 | 00 | 00 | 05 | 17 | ... |  20 |
|                       ...                    |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

Would this be possible? By the way I am using a Postgres database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1. Simple query with an aggregate.

The simplest and fastest way to get the expected result. It is easy to parse the `sales` column within a client program.

```
select item, string_agg(coalesce(sales, 0)::text, ',') sales
from (
    select distinct item_id item, doy
    from generate_series (1, 10) doy  -- change 10 to given n
    cross join entry_daily
    ) sub
left join entry_daily on item_id = item and day_of_year = doy
group by 1
order by 1;

 item |        sales         
------+----------------------
 A1   | 20,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0
 A2   | 11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
(2 rows)
```

### Solution 2. Dynamically created view.

Based on the solution 1 with `array_agg()` instead of `string_agg()`. The function creates a view with a given number of columns.

```
create or replace function create_items_view(view_name text, days int)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    list text;
begin
    select string_agg(format('s[%s] "%s"', i::text, i::text), ',')
    into list
    from generate_series(1, days) i;

    execute(format($f$
        drop view if exists %s;
        create view %s as select item, %s
        from (
            select item, array_agg(coalesce(sales, 0)) s
            from (
                select distinct item_id item, doy
                from generate_series (1, %s) doy
                cross join entry_daily
                ) sub
            left join entry_daily on item_id = item and day_of_year = doy
            group by 1
            order by 1
        ) q
        $f$, view_name, view_name, list, days)
    );
end $$;
```

Usage:

```
select create_items_view('items_view_10', 10);

select * from items_view_10;

 item | 1  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 
------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
 A1   | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 0 |  0
 A2   | 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0
(2 rows)
```

### Solution 3. Crosstab.

Easy to use, but very uncomfortable with the greater number of columns due to the need to define the row format.

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;

select * from crosstab (
    'select item_id, day_of_year, sales
    from entry_daily
    order by 1',
    'select i from generate_series (1, 10) i'
) as ct 
(item_id text, "1" int, "2" int, "3" int, "4" int, "5" int, "6" int, "7" int, "8" int, "9" int, "10" int);

 item_id | 1  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 
---------+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
 A1      | 20 |   |   |   |   |   | 9 |   |   |   
 A2      | 11 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need a table with [all dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql) to fill the blank dates. 100 years of date mean 36,000 rows so no very big. Instead of calculate every time.

allDates:

```
date_id
s_date
```

or created calculating the fields

```
date_id
s_date
doy = EXTRACT(DOY FROM s_date)
year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s_date)
```

Your base query will be **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/300f8/1)**:

```
SELECT           
      AD.year,
      AD.doy,           
      allitems.item_id,
      COALESCE(SUM(ED.sales), 0) as max_sales
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT item_id
     FROM entry_daily 
    ) as allitems
CROSS JOIN alldates AD
LEFT JOIN entry_daily ED
       ON ED.day_of_year = AD.doy
      AND ED.year = AD.year  
      AND ED.item_id = allitems.item_id
WHERE AD.year = 2015
GROUP BY
     AD.year, AD.doy, allitems.item_id
ORDER BY 
     AD.year, AD.doy, allitems.item_id
```

You will have this OUTPUT

```
| year | doy | item_id | max_sales |
|------|-----|---------|-----------|
| 2015 |   1 |      A1 |        20 |
| 2015 |   1 |      A2 |        11 |
| 2015 |   2 |      A1 |         0 |
| 2015 |   2 |      A2 |         0 |
| 2015 |   3 |      A1 |         0 |
| 2015 |   3 |      A2 |         0 |
| 2015 |   4 |      A1 |         0 |
| 2015 |   4 |      A2 |         0 |
| 2015 |   5 |      A1 |         0 |
| 2015 |   5 |      A2 |         0 |
| 2015 |   6 |      A1 |         0 |
| 2015 |   6 |      A2 |         0 |
| 2015 |   7 |      A1 |        39 |
| 2015 |   7 |      A2 |         0 |
| 2015 |   8 |      A1 |         0 |
| 2015 |   8 |      A2 |         0 |
| 2015 |   9 |      A1 |         0 |
| 2015 |   9 |      A2 |         0 |
| 2015 |  10 |      A1 |         0 |
| 2015 |  10 |      A2 |         0 |
```

Then you need install [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html)

and use crosstab to pivot this table  [SAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

Comment: Thx, I will try this tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this self-contained code where we have used 5 instead of 149 to keep the output short.

In (1) we use a single SQL statement, as required, to generate all the series producing a long form result.  Normally in relational databases long form rather than wide form is used and this form may be preferable but in case not we follow this with a conversion to wide form using the reshape2 package.

In (2) we show how to replace the SQL statement with R code that uses the dplyr package.

**1) PostgreSQL** Regarding the SQL statement below, the innermost select generates a table 1, 2, ..., 5 whose column is `day_of_year` which is cross joined with `entry_daily` giving every combination of day_of_year with year and item and keeping only the distinct rows.  This is then left joined with `entry_daily` to pick up the sales numbers which we sum over.

Assuming you have set up postgreSQL to work with SQL as in FAQ#12 on the sqldf home page ( https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf ) the following should illustrate it and is self contained code that you can just copy and paste into your session.

```
library(sqldf)
library(RPostgreSQL)

# input data
entry_daily <- 
structure(list(day_of_year = c(1L, 1L, 7L), year = c(2015L, 2015L, 
2015L), sales = c(20L, 11L, 9L), item_id = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("A1", "A2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("day_of_year", 
"year", "sales", "item_id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

s <- sqldf("select A.item_id, A.year, A.day_of_year, sum(coalesce(B.sales, 0)) sales
       from (select distinct x.day_of_year, y.year, y.item_id
             from (select * from generate_series(1, 5) as day_of_year) as x
                   cross join entry_daily as y) as A
       left join entry_daily as B
       on A.year = B.year and A.day_of_year = B.day_of_year and
          A.item_id = B.item_id
       where A.year = 2015
       group by A.item_id, A.year, A.day_of_year
       order by A.item_id, A.year, A.day_of_year")
```

The output of the above query is this data.frame:

```
> s
   item_id year day_of_year sales
1       A1 2015           1    20
2       A1 2015           2     0
3       A1 2015           3     0
4       A1 2015           4     0
5       A1 2015           5     0
6       A2 2015           1    11
7       A2 2015           2     0
8       A2 2015           3     0
9       A2 2015           4     0
10      A2 2015           5     0
```

If you really need it in wide form then we can do that in R using `dcast` in the reshape2 package:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(s, item_id + year ~ day_of_year, value.var = "sales")
```

giving:

```
  item_id year  1 2 3 4 5
1      A1 2015 20 0 0 0 0
2      A2 2015 11 0 0 0 0
```

**2) dplyr** Note that as an alternative to the SQL statement this R code would compute `s`:

```
library(dplyr)
s2 <- expand.grid(item_id = unique(entry_daily$item_id), 
                  year = 2015, 
                  day_of_year = 1:5) %>%
    left_join(entry_daily) %>%
    group_by(item_id, year, day_of_year) %>%
    summarize(sales = sum(sales, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(item_id, year, day_of_year)
```

giving:

```
> s2
Joining by: c("item_id", "year", "day_of_year")
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: item_id, year [?]

   item_id  year day_of_year sales
    (fctr) (dbl)       (int) (int)
1       A1  2015           1    20
2       A1  2015           2     0
3       A1  2015           3     0
4       A1  2015           4     0
5       A1  2015           5     0
6       A2  2015           1    11
7       A2  2015           2     0
8       A2  2015           3     0
9       A2  2015           4     0
10      A2  2015           5     0
```

Now optionally use the same `dcast` as in (1).