# Postgres pivot table with additional columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I need to realize a pivot table in Postgres, but I have no idea how to do it. The function to use should be the `crosstab()`, but I'm not sure I know how to use it properly.

Given a table like this:

```
column a | column b | column c | value 1 | value 2

       0 |
       1 |
       2 |
       3 |
       4 |
```

I have to get something like this:

```
column c | Column b | 0     | 1     | 2     | 3     | 4 

         |          |value 1|value 1|value 1|value 1|value 1|
         |          |
```

So I need to get the row 0, ... , 4 as columns, and `value 1` as values. `crosstab()` function wants 3 columns, nut I need `column c` and `column b` both to appear.

Comment: share actual value and expected output

Answer (score 1):

`"column c"` and `"column b"` are a so-called "extra" columns. Put them after the row name and before the category:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
      'SELECT "column a", "column c", "column b"
              ,"value 2", "value 1"
       FROM   tbl
       ORDER  BY 1'
     , 'VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)'
   ) AS ct (
    "column a" text
  , "column c" text
  , "column b" text
  , "0" int
  , "1" int
  , "2" int
  , "3" int
  , "4" int);
```

To address your comment:
These are nested *numeric* literals, which need no quoting:

```
     , 'VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)'
```

*String* literals require quoting (I use to dollar-quoting for the outer quote now):

```
     , $$VALUES ('V0'), ('V1'), ('V2'), ('V3'), ('V4')$$
```

Or:

```
     , $$SELECT unnest('{V0,V1,V2,V3,V4}'::text[])$$
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d3a8e5f59d97076c5e83856a01bffd48)*

See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

About `crosstab()`:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

... with extra columns:

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

And consider sane column names. (Assuming given names are just symbolic.)

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: hank you! unluckly, using this code :

SELECT * FROM crosstab( 'SELECT "Animals"."name", "Animals"."age", "Animals"."race","Animals".value FROM "Animals" ORDER BY 1' ,'VALUES (V0), (V1), (V2), (V3), (V4)') AS ct ( "Name" text , "Age" text , "V0" DOUBLE PRECISION , "V1" DOUBLE PRECISION , "V2" DOUBLE PRECISION , "V3" DOUBLE PRECISION , "V4" DOUBLE PRECISION);

is giving me the following error:

ERROR: column "v0" does not exist

Comment: @stefano542: Missing quotes around your string literals. I added some more explanation.