# Postgres CROSSTAB Query not able to get all the expected Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab, unpivot

I have one table in PostgreSQL which is like this **(Img1)**

[image]

From this table I am trying to achieve this **(Img2)**

[image]

I am trying to do this using **CROSSTAB** but in doing so I am not able to get **Roll No** Column. Below is the query that I am using.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CROSSTAB
('select student, subject, marks from dummy order by 1,2') 
AS FINAL
(
    Student TEXT, 
    Geography NUMERIC,
    History NUMERIC,
    Language NUMERIC,
    Maths NUMERIC,
    Music NUMERIC
);
```

How to achieve the expected output as I shown in **(Img2)**?

Comment: Please always provide data as *text*, not as image. Also include the table definition and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use conditional aggregation:

```
select student,
       max(marks) filter (where subject = 'Music') as music,
       max(marks) filter (where subject = 'Maths') as maths,
       max(marks) filter (where subject = 'History') as history,
       max(marks) filter (where subject = 'Language') as language,
       max(marks) filter (where subject = 'Geography') as geography,
       rollno
from t
group by student, rollno;
```

Answer (score 1):

To return ***"extra" columns***, you need the 2-parameter form of the `crosstab()` function (which is typically what you want anyway):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  crosstab(
   'SELECT student, roll_no, subject, marks
    FROM   dummy
    ORDER  BY 1'
 , $$SELECT unnest('{Geography, History, Language, Maths, Music}'::text[])$$
   ) AS final (
      "Student"   text
    , "Roll No"   text  -- extra column(s) go here
    , "Geography" int
    , "History"   int
    , "Language"  int
    , "Maths"     int
    , "Music"     int
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1d5aa371df98499dc3223c56ea91fc7c)*

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)
- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)