# Joining rows in same table - postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table similar to the following -

| id | name | subject | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | English | 50 |
| 1 | XYZ | Math | 30 |

Now I need to something as follows-

| id | name | English | Math |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | 50 | 30 |

I tried `UNION` and `JOIN` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

After I fixed the example in the question to make sense, this would produce your desired result:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT id, name, subject, score
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY 1,3'  -- just "ORDER BY 1" works, too
  , $$VALUES ('Math'::text), ('English')$$
   ) AS ct (id int, name text, "Math" int, "English" int);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WFY0l3jx)

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

In particular, to add "extra" columns (`name` in this example):

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

Comment: What if I have multiple columns that needs to be separated? Example: with score column , I also have total column which needs to be divided based on subject. How can that be done?

Comment: @ladsaylee: Please ask a new question with the necessary detail.